# Set default caret position inside entry widget in Tkinter Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, caret, tkinter-entry

I want to set the default cursor location inside the entry widget when I run the program.

So when I run it I don't have to click inside the widget to start typing.

Here is my minimal code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the `focus` method for the widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus()

tk.mainloop()
```