# How to make a tkinter Entry field that is automatic selected and ready to write into?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want that if the code has been executed, the text field is selected automatically, so that you do not write in teaching when used quickly.

```
import tkinter as tk

def update():
    lab.config(text=(ent.get()))
    root.after(20, update)

root = tk.Tk()
root.maxsize(400, 250)
root.minsize(400, 250)

ent = tk.Entry(root)
ent.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

lab = tk.Label(root)
lab.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.after(20, update)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default cursor position inside entry widget in Tkinter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499960/set-default-cursor-position-inside-entry-widget-in-tkinter-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function `entry.focus()`

```
import tkinter as tk

def update():
    lab.config(text=(ent.get()))
    root.after(20, update)

root = tk.Tk()
root.maxsize(400, 250)
root.minsize(400, 250)

ent = tk.Entry(root)
ent.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
ent.focus()    # <--- RIGHT HERE

lab = tk.Label(root)
lab.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.after(20, update)

root.mainloop()
```