# Is there a way to automatically select an Entrybox in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My GUI is structured such that I have a main class, and each page of my GUI, of which I can navigate between, is instantiated whenever I call it. One of my pages has an entry box, but i have to manually move my cursor and select the entry box to begin typing. Is there a way for the entry box to automatically be selected when I call that page?

Seems like an interesting problem

Comment: [\[tkinter\] set focus to entry](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+set+focus+to+entry)

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Ah, didn't expect it to be called focus. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default cursor position inside entry widget in Tkinter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499960/set-default-cursor-position-inside-entry-widget-in-tkinter-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `focus()`.

For Example, if your entry widget is `e`. Then use `e.focus()`.